# use group by in r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

have a data that looks resembles the below

```
UserID  dob  start_date induction_date  end_date
1       1990-12-12          
1             2010-10-10        
1                       2010-10-12  
1                                      2016-10-31
2       1991-12-14          
2            2011-10-10     
2                      2011-10-12   
2                                     2015-10-31
```

I would like to create a data frame by selecting all the data so that all the data in with a common ID is displayed as one row. I have tried using

```
sec_data <- sqldf('select * from first_data group by id')
```

but I get error

> "Error in match.fun(asfn) :    'c("as.labelled", "as.integer")' is not
>   a function, character or symbol"

Comment: @ggamba, thanks for the edit. It look prettier. Know a page I can reference on styling the SO questions?

Comment: Group by clause aggregates the data, what is your aggregation function? the sql query wouldn't work by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do a hacky way by filling in the blanks then removing the dups. You'll need to do the code below for each column (you didn't provide a dataset so I couldn't test it).

```
value<-0  
for (i in 1:length(first_data)){
  if (first_data$dob[i]!= ''){
    value=first_data$dob[i]
  } else {
  first_data$dob[i]<-value
}
```

After you do that for each column remove the duplicates from your table

```
first_data<-unique(first_data)
```

There is probably a better way but that is the easiest I can think of off the top of my head without a set of data to build something more complicated.